# Query designer in winforms app

Tags: .net, sql, winforms, user-interface

I'm working on a Winforms C# application for a client which replaces their old MS Access based solution. It's a complete rewrite and now uses SQL Server as its database. This software is now in the final stages of development.

One thing that they've just requested is that ability to do custom queries that the software's UI may not currently let them do at the time they need it.

With their old Access solution, they could use the query designer to create their own custom queries. With the winforms/Sql Server solution they can't do this. They don't want to have to write SQL themselves either.

Can anyone think of a good solution to this problem? Perhaps a Winforms library which allows the user to create a graph of business objects and "and|or" logic. Or some other type of UI which allows them to customise queries, almost like they could do in Access (but perhaps more domain specific).

### Update

I've flagged Yaqub's answer as the answer, as this is the closest to what I was looking for at the time. I ended up though writing a custom form for them to generate their queries:

[image]

The "Select table ..." combobox in the second group only shows tables that have been added to the top listbox.

Because the database layout is pretty much set in stone now, I've written code to intelligently calculate any joins required. For example, if they add two indirectly related tables in the top group, then when it generates the SQL, it'll add any required joins to relate those. If the database layout does change, I've made it very easy to change FK references in the query editor's code.

For the condition group, the value control (4th control down in that group) changes depending on the field type (textbox, numerical up/down control, datepicker, checkbox).

When they click on "Run query", they get another form with a gridview displaying the results. In that results form, they can export to a tab delimited file.

I've given them the first version of this, and they seem very happy with it so far.

I didn't want to go the Access route because the whole point of this new version of the software is moving them away from Access (well, not the whole point, as there's a lot more functionality in there too). It seemed a huge step back to keep that dependency with Access there. It also means that if they save lots of custom queries in Access, and I ever change the database schema, I'll most likely break their queries. I don't want them having access to the database like that. In my mind, it's asking for trouble. The only thing that should be touching the database is the new software, and any automated database backups we do - nothing else, especially not users!

Another advantage to doing it within the software, is that I can do post processing on the query results. For example, there are quite a few data analysis algorithms that are run in the software which are written in the .NET code. So I can add fields to this interface that allow them to select the results of these algorithms.

Comment: Folks already gave plenty (and sufficient) solutions: SQL Server Reporting Services (from Ben) or Access database linked to the tables from SQL Server (from Mark)

Comment: @mvaraujo Is this comment regarding my lack of response? I've not replied yet because I want to give a detailed update after I've got it working. I've decided to write a custom query editor which is designed specifically for the software's business objects. Don't worry - I've not forgotten about responding.

Comment: @Dan, yes, I was willing to draw attention to the solutions provided. Sorry for any inconvenience, and of course we await your report on the final solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may find the [Visual SQL Query Designer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43171/A-Visual-SQL-Query-Designer) helpful. It will give you an idea that how you can implement this functionality.

This tool can be used to design SQL queries. Its UI is very basic as compared to SQL Server Management Studio. Its limitation is that it uses `OLEDB` connection string. You can download the source code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/QueryDesigner/QueryDesignerSource.zip).

**EDIT:**

[EasyQuery.NET WinForms](http://devtools.korzh.com/query-builder-winforms/) can be an option but its not free.

[This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/neelamiyer/QueryBuilder12012005042244AM/QueryBuilder.aspx) may also help you a bit.

Comment: There is also this tool http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/Query/ (I have no idea what it's worth). It's seems to be COM, not .NET but it may be interoperable.

Answer (score 3):

One traditional "Microsoft" answer to this is to let them keep using Access... only point it at the SQL server and just let them build their custom queries there.

If you want to get fancy, you can build in a query user role and account, grant only read access to it, and even limit that baked-in role user account to some percentage of the total system load with the Resource Governor stuff if necessary.

There is no shame in prototyping new stuff in Access before rolling it up into real code, either.

Comment: I hate when people downvote without providing an explanation. +1 as I don't see this as a terrible answer.

Comment: @Nick "Let them keep using Access" is not an answer to "This software is now in the final stages of development".

Comment: It might not have been the best answer, but it was still an answer with thought put into it.

Comment: @Danny Beckett, you clearly didn't read the answer the way I intended it. The cooked in C# app is the right way to go for the cooked-in task, but for a few specials who need adhoc reporting, letting them use Access _ALSO_ to do that is probably a better answer than writing/linking-in YA custom query tool. M$ put a 100K man-hours in to Access to make it good at the very task he is wishing he still had.

Comment: @Mark Don't get me wrong, Access is great for some things... but when the OP specifically says he's been tasked to rewrite the application, and it's in the final stages, it's not the most relevant answer to the OP, imo. I'm also obviously interested to see what answers people come up with and which the OP picks, because it's something I'd potentially use myself.

Comment: I have recommended using MS Access to perform queries against a SQL Server database simply because the client already had it.  This is a reasonable solution to the OP's question.

Comment: I'm with Mark. Power users are familiar with Access: let's try do abstract the DB layer, keeping users tools functional. From MS there's a link on how to create an Access DB linked to a SQL Server (the data being linked to, not copied into).

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the SSRS portion of SQL, and giving them access to the ReportBuilder tool?  It has a decent interface for power users.  If you have your primary keys and foreign keys set up in the database, it will recognize those relationships and assist the user in building multi-table queries.  The tool can be downloaded directly from the SSRS web portal, you can integrate the reports directly into your .Net app using the ReportViewer control, or you can use simple HTTP requests to pull them back as Excel, PDF, etc.

Comment: This is also a good idea! Better still, they can share reports, it doesn't swamp the server with 200 requests at once, and you can cook in a limited access user in a connector and reduce them to using only role/app access methods.

Answer (score -2):

I worked on similar tool, basically this tool provides business users to creates report in data grid by drag and drop on business views. We created views on top of tables and maintain metadata information like fields relations etc. metadata tables. If tables are having referential integrity then tool is getting information from sql server master database.

We got help from this utility provided on codeproject. You can go through this basic application which create sql query by drag and drop and you can change as per your need.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43171/A-Visual-SQL-Query-Designer

Comment: This is the exact same link @Yaqub provided in his answer.